# Is there any way to apply concat formula for a range with worksheet_change?

Tags: excel, vba

Recently I have update the MS office version to Office 365 and I found that one of my excel file doesn't work. It is a simple code to apply concatenate formula to some columns when I paste data into the sheet.

What do I need to do with the code?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Range("B23:B4023").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(IF(RC[2]=""TTL"","""",RC[2]),IF(RC[3]="""","""",RC[3]),IF(RC[4]="""","""",RC[4]),IF(R7C4=""Class"",RC[6],RC[7]),RC[8],RC[5])"

End Sub
```

Normally there will be formula apply to column B to join text from column D,E,F,G,H,I&J

However, there is

> run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Worksheet_Change` runs on every content change in the current worksheet. But when this code then also changes content in the same worksheet, then this leads to infinity loops because every of those changes also runs the `Worksheet_Change` again and again.

Setting [Application.EnableEvents property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents) to `False` before the code in `Worksheet_Change` avoids this problem.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Me.Range("B23:B4023").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(IF(RC[2]=""TTL"","""",RC[2]),IF(RC[3]="""","""",RC[3]),IF(RC[4]="""","""",RC[4]),IF(R7C4=""Class"",RC[6],RC[7]),RC[8],RC[5])"
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

But why on earth is it necessary setting that formulas every time content changes in the worksheet? Why not setting it only once?

Comment: Thank you Axel! I am not sure why the creator wants to do it in this way. My temporary solution to bypass the worksheet_change function by adding a button for users.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove the .FormulaR1C1

Comment: thanks puydan! this also work, would you mind explain why this code cause the error? I am a VBA novice actually

Comment: This might look like a "solution" but it does not avoid the infinity loops because every of those changes also runs the `Worksheet_Change` again and again when this code is in `Worksheet_Change`. So it only "works" if you have enough random access memory which then can be wasted by this code.